# sqlalchemy test: adding same user twice not throwing exception when unique=True

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using `Flask` and my `SQLAlchemy` model is

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # noinspection PyShadowingBuiltins
    uuid = Column('uuid', GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
                  unique=True)
    email = Column('email', String, nullable=False, unique=True) # yes unique is True
```

I write the test and import data like

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = dev.SECRET_KEY
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

My test looks like

```
class TestUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

   def test_add_existing_user(self):
        user = User('test_add_existing_user', 'welcome')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(User.query.all()))

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertEquals(2, len(User.query.all())) # just to verify if it saves the same user twice.

    def tearDown(self):
        db.drop_all()
        db.session.remove()
```

When I run this test, I see

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<project path>/tests/test_user.py", line 28, in test_add_existing_user
    self.assertEquals(2, len(User.query.all()))
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

It seems it is not saving the same user twice, but I want the exception to be thrown which I am not receiving, what is that I am not doing right here or missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just realized, I was saving the same `user` twice, rather than creating the new user with sae email.

SQLAlchemy will save the same user as many times as one wants.

Doing the following works

```
    def test_add_existing_user(self):
        user = User('test_add_existing_user', 'welcome')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(User.query.all()))

        db.session.add(User(user.email, 'welcome'))
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Is there any documentation in sql-alchemy stating that?